# PhpStorm - parenthesis formatting on the same line

Tags: phpstorm

How to configure PhpStorm to place parenthesis on the same line when formatting is triggered (<kbd>Ctrl + Alt + L</kbd>)? It currently formats in this way:

```
function()
{

}
```

and I want it to format like that

```
function() {

}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | Code Style | PHP | Wrapping and Braces`
3. `Braces placement | In function declaration = End of line`

Comment: Not sure if it's a newer version change as this is 9 years old but this still breaks formatting when you have a return type. I guess newer PHP versions haven't been catered for yet

Comment: @James Please provide an example (ideally share the file so it can be copy pasted and not re-typed manually) with 1) initial code before reformat, how PhpStorm reformats and how you want it to be reformatted 2) Export your Code Style in XML format and share the file (so it can be imported and played with locally)

Comment: It was just a comment tbh for others to not be confused, not a report. It can be seen here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-31618/Function-opening-brace-is-moved-to-the-next-line-when-arguments-span-multiple-lines-an-a-return-type-PHP-7-is-specified the missing settings options to control this fully is discussed in the comments there

Comment: @James That ticket states that it has been fixed in 2016.2.2 version (around 7 years ago) I've tried formatting the code from that ticket... and it seems to be doing OK here in 2023.1.4 version, unless I'm looking at the wrong thing ofc. **P.S.** There is also the "Function declaration parameters | Keep ')' and '{' on one line" option that can also have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

1. Settings/Preferences
2. Editor | Code Style | PHP | Braces Placement
3. In function declaration = End of line
4. Place braces for empty functions/methods on one line